# LaTeX table with combined columns - labels split

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I'm trying to make a table in LaTeX with the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c||c|c|c| }
         & \multicolumn{2}{c}Liberal Arts &
         & \multicolumn{2}{c}Engineering \\
         & women & men & & women & men \\
  \hline
  accept & 96 &  ? & accept & ?  & 386 \\
  \hline
  reject & ?  & 45 & reject & 12 & ?   \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

But the combined column labels end up getting an extra space after their first character.

[image]

How do I prevent the extra space?

Comment: Why on Earth is this considered off-topic?

Comment: because it would be a topic for tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, it should be `\multicolumn{2}{c||}{Liberal Arts}`. Without the `{}` around the argument, latex will only take the first character as argument of `\multicolumn`

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c||c|c|c| }
         & \multicolumn{2}{c||}{Liberal Arts} &
         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Engineering} \\
         & women & men & & women & men \\
  \hline
  accept & 96 &  ? & accept & ?  & 386 \\
  \hline
  reject & ?  & 45 & reject & 12 & ?   \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems obvious now that you point it out.  Thank you!

Comment: @KirkD-CO You're welcome!